# If-statement does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have the following problem with JavaScript:
I have an array with booleans I received from my database and want to do some action if a specific field is true.
Because it didn't work I wrote the following:

```
if(data.participants[i].attended) {
    console.log(data.participants[i].attended);
}
```

In my opinion that should just print 1 or nothing on the console, but -because 0 means false in JS- never 0. But when I let it run it prints 0 on the console.

Comment: Is it [`0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) or [`"0"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)?

Comment: "0" is truthy, 0 is falsey

Comment: It's 0 without any quotationmarks

Comment: Well, yes.  But that doesn't say whether it's a string or not.  You can usually tell what sort it is - eg [in Chrome they're different colours](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LJMyM.png).

Comment: in that case, `console.log(typeof data.participants[i].attended);` if the output is "string" then it's "0"

Comment: @JamesThorpe so it is in firefox as well

Comment: That was what confused me. I thought If it's displayed without quotationmarks it is a integer, but you were right it probably was a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse value of variable as integer like this:

```
if(parseInt(data.participants[i].attended)) {
    console.log(data.participants[i].attended);
}
```

Comment: Thank you really much. That was the solution.

Comment: Please mark it as your answer for others who are looking for the same thing.

Comment: I would like to but I am not allowed to. Just in 5 minutes.